# Python Kivy ScrollViev

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Could someone send me an example of code in kivy language if possible, containing simple horizontal boxlayout where's on one side a scrollview with buttons and on the other side just a label named "test label". I cant figure how the scrollview works and im sure that'd help. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034014/kivy-scroll-view-does-not-scroll), but that looks really compicated to me and i can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the scrollview most contain one widget and commonly will be a Layout contains many widgets or one big widget here a simple example

main.py :

```py
from kivy.app import App


class Main(App):
    pass
Main().run()
```

main.kv file

```py
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    Label:
        text:'test label'
    ScrollView:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:"vertical"
            size_hint_y:None
            height:self.minimum_height
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'

            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
            Button:
                size_hint_y:None
                height:'100dp'
```